# Mistake in "create procedure" statement

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a procedure to insert data in a MariaDB (10.1.17) using HeidiSQL but the statement fails with the error "SQL Error(1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11"

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `uspaddpost`(IN `_siteparseid` INT, IN `_user`         
VARCHAR(255), IN `_post` TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE _userid INT;
DECLARE _siteid INT;
SELECT `SiteID` INTO _siteid FROM tblsiteparse WHERE `SiteParseID` = _siteparseID LIMIT 1;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT `UserID` FROM tblusers WHERE `User` = _user) THEN
    INSERT INTO tblusers (`UserID`, `SiteID`) VALUES (_user, _siteid);
SELECT `UserID` INTO _userid FROM tblusers WHERE `User` = _user;
INSERT INTO tblposts (`UserID`,`SiteParseID`, `Post`) VALUES (_userid, _siteparseid, _post);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each "IF" has to by closed by an "END IF;"